# Fix player movement?

Tags: character, rigidbody

My character follows camera direction. my issue is when i look at sky and walk or run my character goes up ! the same thing happen when i look down and walk back.

```
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    movs = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    movs = cam.TransformDirection(movs);

    rb.AddForce(movs * speed);

    float maxVelocity = 5f;
    rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxVelocity);
```

What I need is make it work normally. like GTA or GoW.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Unity's \`transform.translate()\` to translate relative to an object but only using two axis](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111313/using-unitys-transform-translate-to-translate-relative-to-an-object-but-onl), which also talks about the issue of a camera-relative movement vector pointing into/off the ground instead of parallel.

Comment: I tried to copy your last post and modify it to fit my script but didn't work. can you just fix my code. I think my problem is with "TransformDirection".

Comment: "but didn't work" is *never* enough information to diagnose a problem. If you want help, you absolutely must include what you tried and a detailed description of what errors you encountered.