# Unity smooth local rotation around one Axis, oriented toward a target

Tags: c#, rotation, quaternion

[image]
[image]

I want to acheive the same rotation you see in the inspector.
In short: a smooth local Y rotation, toward a target

I have a Vector3 orientation:
`Vector3 dirOrientation = targetToLook.position - movingCamera.position;`

So, every Update, what should I do ? I try many thing, but I don't realy understand Quaternion...

I just want to rotate localy in Y, toward a precise moving target, NOT in X or Z. and smoothly with some Lerp or Slerp.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [trick discussed in a similar question here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/100887/39518) and [also here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/133357/39518), we can define a helper method to point our local Y axis exactly in a particular direction, while turning our local Z axis to face (as close as possible) toward another direction.

```
Quaternion TurretLookRotation(Vector3 approximateForward, Vector3 exactUp)
{
    Quaternion rotateZToUp = Quaternion.LookRotation(exactUp, -approximateForward);
    Quaternion rotateYToZ = Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f);

    return rotateZToUp * rotateYToZ;
}
```

Now we can use that in Update to face toward our target:

```
void Update() {
    // Form the direction we want to look towards
    Vector3 offsetToTarget = target.position - transform.position;

    // Preserve our current up direction
    // (or you could calculate this as the direction away from the planet's center)
    Vector3 up = transform.up;

    // Form a rotation facing the desired direction while keeping our
    // local up vector exactly matching the current up direction.
    Quaternion desiredOrientation = TurretLookRotation(offsetToTarget, up);

    // Move toward that rotation at a controlled, even speed regardless of framerate.
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
                            transform.rotation,
                            desiredOrientation,
                            maxDegreesPerSecond * Time.deltaTime
                         );

}
```

Comment: Hello, your methode create a brutal flip upside/down when we are at an extreme angle, do you have any way of resolve this ? thanks

Comment: I'll need more details to diagnose the problem. Please provide a reproducible test case and a detailed description of how the specific symptoms you're observing differ from your desired behaviour.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENJ9X9Lobk8&feature=youtu.be
It's the rotation up/down of the player: when I have a perpendicular normal: the player flip upside/down instant...

I found something interesting: when I reduce the speed of the rotation, the problem disapear, when I have a fast speed, for non perpendicular case, the movement is smooth and fast, and when i'm perdendicular, the rotation is instant. Weird

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem shown in the video using just the code above. The object rotates smoothly no matter how I change the target's position or desired up vector, even at high `maxDegreesPerSecond` speeds. The sudden snap might be coming from the code you're using to turn the object to match its new surface. I recommend posting a new Question containing a minimal, complete, verifiable example of all the code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry @DMGregory, the probleme was something Else.
I have one other question if I May: If I want to get as result a Vector3, it seems like desiredOrientation.eulerAngle is not enought. Any thought?

Comment: No worries. Want to share an answer in case it helps others spot similar issues? To help track down the cause faster in future, it's often useful to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example in a new project, so you can isolate the code/project setup responsible.

Comment: I Have on other question if I May: If I want to get an Vector3 as result, desiredOrientation.eulerAngle doesn't work. I have managed to get my Vectro3 by creating an empty object, named ``Transform rotateEmpty``, and then with my ``Quaternion desiredOrientation = TurretLookRotation(offsetToTarget, up);``, I set to my empty object the desired rotation: ``rotateEmpty.rotation = desiredOrientation``, and then I get my final Vector3 with ``Vector3 desiredVectorOrientation = rotateEmpty.forward.``

Do you know a way to get this vector without an empty object ? thanks

Comment: To share a question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top-right of the site. It looks like what you're describing is equivalent to `Vector3 desiredForward = desiredOrientation * Vector3.forward` though.

Comment: Thanks ! it's exactly what I wanted. I didn't knew I could multiply quaternion by vector  like that. Sorry again for the mess. Next time i will not hesitate to create a separate question.