# Rotation Problem in Mario galaxy like controller

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, quaternion

i'm doing a Mario galaxy like CCC.
And I have a serious rotation problem, may be Gimble lock, or maybe not.

So first, I have a parent object ("**PLAYER**") who can rotate toward a planet:
https://youtu.be/j3VkemYQTa8

With this 3 line:

```
Vector3 dirOrientation = GetNormal() //here the normal collision
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(PLAYER.transform.up, dirOrientation) * PLAYER.transform.rotation;
PLAYER.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(PLAYER.transform.rotation, targetRotation, speedRotate);
```

Ok, next, I want to rotate the child object ("**CHILDPLAYER**"), who contain the render, according to the input of the player
See in editor:
https://youtu.be/4Sb8t82OT-E

So here... I managed to get the direction of the input, according to the camera.
See in blue, the directionnal line: the Vector3 point to the good direction according to the player and the camera, yes !
https://youtu.be/4TvPsXp-W9U

```
Vector2 dirInput = playerInput.GetDirInput();//input player with the stick, X,Y
//here REFOBJECT is the camera (who dictate the "forward" of the player
Vector3 relativeDirection = REFOBJECT.right * dirInput.x + REFOBJECT .forward * dirInput.y;
Debug.DrawRay(CHILDPLAYER.position, relativeDirection, Color.cyan, 0.4f);
```

But now... As you see even if I have the good direction (cf blue line in the vidéo). I can't manage to rotate the child gameObject accordingly... I have to localy rotate smoothly the **CHILDPLAYER** only in Y toward my new calculated vector...

Here the code I use to rotate the **CHILDPLAYER**, with my **relativeDirection** Vector3:

```
CHILDPLAYER.localRotation = DirObject(CHILDPLAYER.localRotation, relativeDirection, turnRate);

public Quaternion DirObject(Quaternion rotation, Vector3 dir, float turnRate)
    {
        float heading = Mathf.Atan2(-dir.x * turnRate * Time.deltaTime, dir.z * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);

        Quaternion _targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        float x = 0;
        float y = heading * -1 * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        float z = 0;

        _targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z);
        rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(rotation, _targetRotation, turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        return (rotation);
    }
```

See the final result:
https://youtu.be/lSQQFDDuj7U
Here, I'm going ALWAYS DOWN with the stick... and even if the direction calculated in relativeDirection is good, the child player rotate itself... ...

[image]

Comment: "I have to localy rotate smoothly the CHILDPLAYER only in Y toward my new calculated vector..." This sounds a lot like your previous question ["Smooth local rotation around one axis, oriented toward a target"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167389/unity-smooth-local-rotation-around-one-axis-oriented-toward-a-target) - does an answer to that question solve this one? Or do you have a remaining problem to sort out even with a solution to the first question in-hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks yo @DMGregory, here is the answers:
[Unity smooth local rotation around one Axis, oriented toward a target](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167389/unity-smooth-local-rotation-around-one-axis-oriented-toward-a-target)

Sorry for the duplicate, I thought this was 2 separate problem. It was not.