# Manually update rotation of only Y-axis on Agent

Tags: unity, ai

I have some code to manage to rotation of my Navmesh agents:

```
if (Agent.isActiveAndEnabled && Agent.hasPath)
        {
            if (Agent.velocity.sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Agent.velocity.normalized);
            }
        }
```

It's causing my some issues with some odd rotations on the x/z axis for 1-2 frames every now and then, is there some way I can get this exact behaviour but only modify the y-axis?

Comment: I've tried this and most other common solutions I can find, in the end the only thing that worked was this: `Quaternion tempRot = transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Agent.velocity.normalized);
                tempRot.x = 0;
                tempRot.z = 0;
                transform.rotation = tempRot;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your agents are always oriented vertically, this is reasonably straightforward. Just project your velocity into the horizontal plane, and look toward that. This can always be accomplished with a pure yaw, no pitch/roll required:

```
var projected = Agent.velocity;
projected.y = 0f;

if(!Mathf.Approximately(projected.sqrMagnitude, 0f))    
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(projected);
```

The `if` check just declines to rotate if the agent has stopped or is travelling purely vertically, which helps avoid a sudden snap to 0-degrees in those cases. Instead, we'll just keep our current yaw.

If your agent can be aligned arbitrarily, then [you can use this technique explained in existing answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/167395/39518) to locally yaw to face your velocity while keeping your current/desired local up vector fixed.

Comment: This seems to work the same way the code I have in the comment above, but seems a bit nicer. I can prob also replace my `Agent.velocity.sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon` check with ur `!Mathf.Approximately(projected.sqrMagnitude, 0f)`